# Why is this limit $0$?

Tags: limits

If we have $g'(f(c)) = \lim_{y \to f(c)} \frac{g(y)-g(f(c))}{y-f(c)}$

and let $d(y)$ be the difference:

$d(y) = \frac{g(y)-g(f(c))}{y-f(c)} - g'(f(c))$

Where $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $f$ is also differentiable at $c$.

Then why does

$\lim_{y \to f(c)} d(y) =0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by the difference rule for limits. Since $g'(f(c))$ is constant, $\lim_{y\to f(c)} g'(f(c)) = g'(f(c))$. So

$$\lim_{y\to f(c)} d(y) = \lim_{y\to f(c)} \frac{g(y) - g(f(c))}{y - f(c)} - \lim_{y\to f(c)} g'(f(c)) = g'(f(c)) - g'(f(c)) = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for this response, it makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

$f(c)$ is just a fixed number in your limit; it does not depend on $y$. So just call it $z$ instead. Now you're really just calculating that

$$\lim_{y \to z} \left ( \frac{g(y) - g(z)}{y-z} - g'(z) \right ) = 0$$

which is just a restatement of the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Thank-you for this response, that clears things up!